# Penetration testing real-life practice

Tags: penetration-test

I see a lot of similar question but my is different. I had done a lot of challenges like Kioptrix  and De-ice. But I'm not sure that this is real life pen testing. I mean this is so simple only nmap and metasploit (and some web app hacking). So is there something closer to real life penetration testing?

Answer (score 5):

Something closer to real life requires an infrastructure with systems and networking equipment. You can virtualize that but it still requires some resources to set up and run. That's why you have to pay for most of the good labs.

[BackTrack PenTesting Edition lab](http://pentestlab.org/lab-in-a-box/) is an all-in-one penetration testing lab environment that includes all of the hosts, network infrastructure, tools, and targets necessary to practice penetration testing. It includes: a DMZ network with two hosts targets, an “internal” network with one host target and a pre-configured firewall.

[OSCP](http://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-certifications/oscp-offensive-security-certified-professional/), [OSCE](http://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-certifications/osce-offensive-security-certified-expert/), [SANS 660](http://www.sans.org/course/advanced-penetration-testing-exploits-ethical-hacking) and [HackinkDOJO](http://hackingdojo.com/lab/) are some of the paid courses that have good practical labs.

[CTF365](http://ctf365.com) is a continuous real world Capture The Flag with free and paid services.

You can also [build your own security lab](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470179864).

And if you want **real world** pentesting, go do bug bounties and get paid for it at [Bugcrowd](https://bugcrowd.com) and [HackerOne](https://hackerone.com).